# (Linux dotnet)output “Segmentation fault” when run "dotnet restore"

Tags: .net-core

I installed dotnet-sdk in Deepin(base Debian),but when I run "dotnet restore" that output "Segmentation fault".

Install .NET Core SDK document (https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#linuxdebian)

Command Line:

```
root@ylooq:~/soft$ cd ../
root@ylooq:~$ mkdir hello
root@ylooq:~$ cd hello/
root@ylooq:~/hello$ ls
root@ylooq:~/hello$ dotnet new
Created new C# project in /home/ylooq/hello.
root@ylooq:~/hello$ dotnet restore
log  : Restoring packages for /home/ylooq/hello/project.json...
Segmentation fault
root@ylooq:~/hello$ ls
Program.cs  project.json
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using deepin 15 which is based on Debian Unstable branch.

Dotnet core depends on old versions of libcurl3 and the issue causes libssl1.0.0 library, which comes with libcurl3.

This is a list of packages that dotnet-sdk-2.0.0-preview2(for Debian) depends on:

```
libc6 (>= 2.14), libcurl3 (>= 7.16.2), libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1), 
libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.10+dfsg~), liblttng-ust0, libstdc++6 (>= 4.8),
libunwind8, libuuid1 (>= 2.16), zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4), libssl1.0.0
```

In Debian 8(jessie) you can find these packages. Please try adding debian jessie repo to sources.list:

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie main non-free contrib
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie main non-free contrib
```

These links might be helpful to you since you might have to use apt-pinning :) in order to download older versions of packages:

1. [Apt pinning](http://jaqque.sbih.org/kplug/apt-pinning.html)
2. [Issue of libcurl3](https://gist.github.com/Yutsa/d382721f26be73e4112bd903cf6b0490)